# C passing string by reference to function

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, double-pointer

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun1(int **iptr){
printf("%d ", **iptr); //shows value
}

void fun2(char **sptr){
//printf("%s", **sptr); shows segmentation fault 
printf("%s", *sptr);  //shows string
}

int main(){
char *str = "Hi";
int *x, a = 10;

x = &a;
fun1(&x);
fun2(&str);
return 0;
}
```

Can anybody explain in short what's going on?
might be silly but i asked it anyway...

Comment: Because `printf` is expecting a pointer as a parameter for the `%s` specifier and a non-pointer for `%d`

Comment: Your two codes are not similar. Make a string variable, set a pointer to its address, use exactly as the pointer to int variable. Then compare behaviour.

Comment: `char **sptr ... printf("%s", **sptr); shows segmentation fault`  --> A good compiler will warn of how this code is bad **before** you even need to run the code.  Save yourself  time and enable all compiler warnings.  What warning do you get?

Comment: thanks for help..im new to this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing an integer, you pass the integer itself to `printf`.
When printing a string of characters, you pass the address of the first character. In other words, you pass the pointer to the string.